# Estimating Weight of Human Skeletal Muscle?

Tags: human-anatomy, human-physiology, muscles, nutrition, bone-biology

Is there a way to measure the weight of skeletal muscle?  I understand [body fat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_fat_percentage) and [lean body mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lean_body_mass) can be measured by: [skin fold calipers](https://nutriactiva.com/blogs/body-fat/what-is-a-skinfold-caliper), [electrical impedance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bioelectrical_impedance_analysis), table lookup based on [formula](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiTxpqpqbb8AhXNFlkFHQkTBksQFnoECA4QAw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov%2Fpmc%2Farticles%2FPMC6650177%2F&usg=AOvVaw2vuDFFczkjk-Dz74KcYTWR) of weight, age, and height.  I have not seen a method to determine [skeletal muscle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeletal_muscle).  I asked an endocrinologist and they were not aware of a method.

I suspect subtracting the weight of the skeletal bones, skin tissue and [organs](https://www.verywellhealth.com/how-much-do-your-organs-weigh-4105246) from the lean body mass weight could determine weight of skeletal muscle.  It seems this number could vary greatly be the person unless perhaps people who handle deceased people have accurate measurements of the above for age, weight, height, etc...

It would be useful to know the weight of skeletal muscle because it could be used to determine body energy expenditure, as lean muscle uses more calories than fat.

Comment: You probably know that **evidence** of prior research is required on this site. It's a good question. Editing what you've found so far would make it better. :)

Comment: Updated with research references.  Are my categories ok for this?

Comment: Did you search "how to determine skeletal muscle mass"?

Comment: I did and the calculations are for Lean Body Mass (LBM) = Total Weight – Fat Mass which includes Organs, Skin, Bones, Body Water, Muscle Mass.  I think I'm looking for Muscle Mass, which will allow me to multiply it by 6 kcal/lbs and fat, 2 kcal/lbs to get a more accurate calculation of BMR.  I don't think the 6 kcal/lbs is supposed to include organs, skin, bones and body water... I suspect this factor is for muscle tissue only.

Comment: Hmm, I see that you're correct that the first few hits do refer to lean body weight, but on the first page of hits (for me) is a good article specifically on skeletal muscle estimation, which discusses the method with which I'm most familiar.

Comment: What link are you referring to?  I see https://www.healthline.com/health/muscle-mass-percentage, which uses a estimated chart and the numbers don't add up to the correct BMR.  There are some formulas here, but again it is rough estimate and don't measure if a person has lifted lots of weights https://www.frontiersin.org/files/Articles/505707/fendo-11-00031-HTML/image_m/fendo-11-00031-t001.jpg.  There is suggestion of using an MRI, water displacement.  There is a formula using impedance https://journals.physiology.org/doi/full/10.1152/jappl.2000.89.2.465.

Comment: Also, Creatine ( methyl-d3) dilution in urine for estimation of total body skeletal muscle mass.  The only problem here is if a body builder is taking creatine supplement, it will throw off the results.  Are you referring to this?

Comment: [This](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fendo.2020.00031/full) was the article I saw towards the bottom of the first page of hits. It compares two methods of estimating skeletal muscle mass. The method I'm familiar with is that using a DXA scan, although I'm passingly familiar that one can use MRI, but have not ever bothered becoming knowledgeable about it, because DXA scans are so easy and so much less expensive. Good research on your part, btw.